# How to make custom Visual C++ button?

Tags: visual-c++, button, customization

To be precise, I don't want to use standard rectangular buttons. Is there a way to create your own buttons and incorporate them into Visual C++ application? For example, a button in a shape of a fruit, animal, random object...? How can this be achieved?

Comment: A button is a UI gadget, it doesn't have anything to do with the C++ language.  There are *many* UI frameworks, your question doesn't give any clue whatsoever which one you are using.  The best way to ask an SO question is by writing several paragraphs that describe what you've tried so far to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common approaches to custom buttons. The first is to use the owner-draw optional style on a standard button. With this style set you receive a message (WM_DRAWITEM) when the button needs to be painted and you paint it yourself any way you like. A second approach is to draw the image on an existing window and analyze mouse messages to determine when a click is on the image. The common toolbar uses this approach: It doesn't really have button controls on it, just pictures that look like buttons. With this second approach you are not limited to clicks on rectangular areas.

Answer (score 0):

define your own callback function for button
   SetWindowLong(hMyButtonWnd,GWL_WNDPROC,(LONG)&MyButtonProc);

and here example of button callback

    `LRESULT CALLBACK MyButtonProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
    {
        if (message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            bBtnClicked = true;
            bBtnDown = true;
            SetCapture(hWnd);
            nMouseX = LOWORD(lParam);
            nMouseY = HIWORD(lParam);
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,false);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        }
        else if (message == WM_LBUTTONUP)
        {
            bBtnClicked = false;
            bBtnDown = false;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,false);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
            RECT rec;
            GetClientRect(hWnd,&rec);
            if (nMouseX > rec.left && nMouseY > rec.top
                && nMouseX < rec.right && nMouseY < rec.bottom)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL,L"Button clicked",L"Test",MB_OK);
            }
            ReleaseCapture();
        }
        else if (message == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            nMouseX = LOWORD(lParam);
            nMouseY = HIWORD(lParam);
            RECT rec;
            GetClientRect(hWnd,&rec);
            if (nMouseX <= rec.left || nMouseY <= rec.top
                || nMouseX >= rec.right || nMouseY >= rec.bottom) bBtnDown = false;
            InvalidateRect(hWnd,NULL,false);
            UpdateWindow(hWnd);
        }
        if (message == WM_PAINT)
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC dc = BeginPaint(hWnd,&ps);
            HDC c_dc = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
            if (bBtnDown) SelectObject(c_dc,hBtnDown);
            else SelectObject(c_dc,hBtnUp);
            RECT rec;
            GetClientRect(hWnd,&rec);
            BitBlt(dc,0,0,rec.right,rec.bottom,c_dc,0,0,SRCCOPY);
            DeleteDC(c_dc);
            EndPaint(hWnd,&ps);
            return 0;
        }
        else return CallWindowProc(DefProc,hWnd,message,wParam,lParam);
        return 1;
    }`